Excel - concatenate all instances of text before delimiter in single cell
I have a column of strings in the following format:
Xxx, yyy, zzz, Need this|AAA, BBB, CCC, And this|Xxx, BBB, CCC, This too...

The number of "|" delimiters is unspecified and varies in each cell in the column. For each of the rows, I need to extract a list of text between each | delimiter and its previous comma.
I found how to get each one individually:
=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(cellvalue,"|",", ",-1))

However, I'm not sure how to loop through the X delimiters in each cell to get a list of the text before every delimiter. I'd like these values to be in a list in one cell per row separated by a delimiter.
Bonus if you can add in a method to make the list unique values only!
Appreciate that this would be easier with a different programme but Excel is all I can work with :)

You could have tried something like this:


=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,TEXTAFTER(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,"|"),", ",-1))


To have only unique:
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,UNIQUE(TEXTAFTER(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,"|"),", ",-1)))


NOTE: I have used line-feeds as delimiter to join( remember to click on wrap text from Home Ribbon), one can use comma , or semi-colons ; as well or any other as per their suit.

If you have a range of data as below, then wrap the above within a LAMBDA() helper function like BYROW() or MAP(), but I prefer in using the copy down option, since TEXTJOIN() or ARRAYTOTEXT() functions has character limitations, however, may be your records will be within limits, still.


=MAP(A1:A9,LAMBDA(α, 
 TEXTJOIN("; ",1,UNIQUE(TEXTAFTER(
 TEXTSPLIT(α,,"|"),", ",-1)))))



For fun and if applicable, try to utilize REGEXREPLACE():

Formula in C1:
=REGEXREPLACE(A1:A3,"([^,|]+)(,\s*(?1))*(?=(?2))(((?2))\|(?=.*\4(\||$)))?,?\s*",)


Thanks for adding regex options, now that I have joined the 'insiders' I'm able to test them on Mac ;)

They are so much fun @nkalvi. I have some cool tips over on my ☕ page.

Taking the last column, after splitting by column (,) and row (|):
A1:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)) for automatically expanding entries added later.
=BYROW(
    A1:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)),
    LAMBDA(row_,
        TEXTJOIN(
            CHAR(10),
            ,
            UNIQUE(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(row_, ",", "|", FALSE, , ""), , -1))
        )
    )
)



REGEX
Look ahead for | or end of line (?=(\||$)), then look behind for , with (?<=,) and gather any char *, but [^,|], collecting all matches with REGEXEXTRACT(,,1):
=BYROW(
    A1:A4,
    LAMBDA(r,
        TEXTJOIN(
            REPT(CHAR(10), 2),
            ,
            UNIQUE(REGEXEXTRACT(r, "(?<=,)[^,|]*(?=(\||$))", 1))
        )
    )
)


